# How do you rescue a stranded out of fuel ship in Aurora 4X?

Tags: aurora-4x

In [*Aurora 4X*](http://aurorawiki.pentarch.org/index.php?title=Main_Page), I've managed to build this *Halifax* class of ship with some internal fusion twin [engine](http://aurorawiki.pentarch.org/index.php?title=Engine) and [geological survey](http://aurorawiki.pentarch.org/index.php?title=Geological_Survey_Sensors) equipment; I have a few of them which I all [*detached*](http://aurorawiki.pentarch.org/index.php?title=Fast_OB_Creation_window_and_Basic_Fleet_Orders) from any battle group. I've set them to survey the nearest body and to return to Earth when they have less than 20% fuel, so they've scattered all over the place and I'm getting feedback about mineral composition and availability. But this one ship is stranded far away from our solar system and its fuel resources are depleted, as the log shows. It's just a simple ship with a crew of 61; at the helm, Captain Pélissier, with an interest in [xenology](http://aurorawiki.pentarch.org/index.php?title=Teams#Xenology); in service for 5 years 10 months 15 days...

[image]

<sup>*A surveying expedition has gone wrong. Saving 20% of fuel may not be enough when ordered to resupply directly from home (Earth). A more careful planning was required.*</sup>

---

- How do you mount a *rescue* operation in such cases?

  - Can I just re-purpose an existing ship and send it to share some fuel to enable the
    *Halifax 006* a safe return home?
  - Do I need to build a specific ship; do I need the [*salvage
    module*](http://aurorawiki.pentarch.org/index.php?title=Salvage)? Is the only solution towing the ship back to earth with a
    [*ship to ship tractor* beam](http://aurorawiki.pentarch.org/index.php?title=Ship_to_Ship_Tractor)?
  - Where (how) would you set it so that the towing "destination" of such a ship
    would be the *Halifax 006* ((how) do you make the *Halifax 006* appear in
    the [task group](http://aurorawiki.pentarch.org/index.php?title=Task_Groups) window as a [*location*](http://aurorawiki.pentarch.org/index.php?title=File:Task_Groups.png)?)?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

In addition to your own answer, there are several more possible options.

1) Instead of manual fuel transfer, you can just merge the two TGs and equalize the fuel levels. You can then split them again or let them go home together. This is useful, when you have trouble judging how much fuel the stranded ship needs.

2) As you stated yourself, there are ships available, which can tow other ships (tractor beam module), though those are usually built to transport space stations to their intended location, they can also be used to rescue a stranded ship. Or to drag wrecks to a spot, where your salvagers can get to. Very versatile shiptype.

3) I'm not quite sure about that one, as I haven't played Aurora in a while, but you can build tanker-ships and I believe you can order them to automatically refuel nearby ships. At the least, you can order your survey ship to refuel at the tanker, allowing you to use it as a mobile fuel depot for future endeavours.

The salvage module is used to harvest resources and modules from wrecked ships, it won't be of any help in your situation.

Finally, keep an eye on your fuel levels, as you recognized yourself, 20% wasn't enough to get back home. To avoid this in the future, check the amount of fuel your ship needed to reach its first mission destination and keep that much in reserve. If you are surveying other systems, it's always wise to setup a fuel depot there to avoid long trips home to earth.

Comment: By the way, when a ship gets stranded due to battle damage, i.e. engine destroyed and not enough spare parts available to repair, towing it home for repairs is usually the best option. Sending spare parts and waiting for it to repair itself takes longer and you still have to go home to repair the structural damage.

Comment: I'll select your answer as a broader take on the Q. whereas my answer, which is really about interface nuts and bolts is mainly technical, if accurate and pertinent. Thanks again! p.s. don't hesitate to further edit down the line if you ever try again the tankers and such!

Comment: Well, even if you can order a tanker to automatically refuel nearby ships, it'll only be useful, when a ship is stranded. Tankers are big slow freighters (at least it doesn't make much sense equipping them with inefficient, high powered military engines, when their objective is to provide fuel); so it's very unlikely your tanker will ever catch a survey ship it's trying to refuel and it makes much more sense just to tell the survey ship to go to the tanker.

Comment: Additionally later in the game you might try survey carriers. I.e. big ships with lots of fuel and several survey shuttles. You just send the carrier to a system and it's the mobile base for the survey vessels, which then don't need a jump drive and can easily refuel and repair at the mothership. It was a bit of a hassle when I last tried it (v. 6.4), as you couldn't just tell the carrier to automatically survey and have it send out it its shuttles that way, though this may have changed by now.

Answer (score 2):

The first thing to do is to *remove* all outstanding orders the stranded ship has assigned as well as to reset its *default/conditional orders* to none (this allows for the out of fuel status to stop impeding with turn progression). Then pick a Task group with a ship with fuel to spare from the *Task Groups* window and just check... *Task Groups*, then select the group name the stranded ship belongs to from the *Locations* selection, then set the action to *Move to*. Allow some time for the ship/group you selected to reach its destination. Following that, in the *Individual Units* window, select the ship with the extra fuel; in the *Miscellaneous* tab you'll find a *Manual Fuel Transfer* widget (also a *tractor link* widget...) with a drop down from where to select the stranded ship and specify the amount of fuel you want to transfer. Transfer fuel as needed to the stranded ship to enable its safe return home (if you give it the order)!

[image]

<sup>Here the AM Razor Group, containing the *AM Razor* ship is tasked with moving to the Battle Task group (containing our stranded ship, now the *Restigouche*) for the rescue operation from the Task Groups window. Once the destination is reached, the Individual Units Details window is used to transfer fuel from the *AM Razor* to the *Restigouche*.</sup>